# Imagemagick convert low quality gif after chop

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to chop the following gif as to remove four of the inner videos:
[image]
I use this command:
`convert  bair_action_free_00232.gif -gravity NorthWest -chop 256x0+65+0 vid_pred.gif`

The result looks really bad; the black frame flickers and the text looks awful.

[image]

Adding `-quality 99` doesn't help. Any tips?

Gif Reference: https://alexlee-gk.github.io/video_prediction/

Comment: Is there a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
convert vid.gif -coalesce -chop 256x0+65+0 -delay 80 result.gif
```

[image]